# Ubuntu 14.04 boot issue

Tags: boot

My system was not booting anymore, so I ran the "[Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)".

Now Boot Repair seems to be stuck during:

`Purge kernels then reinstall last kernal mapper/ubuntu-vg-root (ins). This may require several minutes...`

It has been displaying that message for over two hours now.

I'm pretty much a complete novice Ubuntu user, can anyone help me out?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9568882/

Comment: Try using this command to free up the space in Kernel,  apt-get -f install, and later try with the rebooting.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion - that didn't solve the issue though. Boot now hangs in GRUB.